# PAM deny rule not applied on Ubuntu in Google Cloud

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, pam, ubuntu-18.04

I added

```
auth requisite pam_deny.so
```

as the first line of every file in `/etc/pam.d/` (including `sshd`), but SSH connections still succeed without a problem. This is on a default Google Cloud Ubuntu instance, so it has some mysterious sort of authentication set up. **How can I get my deny command to be applied?**

### Basic checks

- `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has the line `UsePAM yes`
- `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has other authentication methods disabled:

  ```
  HostbasedAuthentication no
  IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes
  IgnoreRhosts yes
  PasswordAuthentication no
  ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
  KerberosAuthentication no
  GSSAPIAuthentication no
  UseLogin no
  ```
- `/etc/nsswitch.conf` has no custom `passwd` entries:

  ```
  passwd:         compat 
  group:          compat 
  shadow:         compat 
  gshadow:        files 

  hosts:          files dns 
  networks:       files 

  protocols:      db files 
  services:       db files 
  ethers:         db files 
  rpc:            db files
  ```
- restarted `sshd` service
- stopped all services with `google` in the name
- no hints about auth mechanism in `journalctl -f` when logging in by SSH
- OS Login has been deactivated for the Google Cloud project and `google_oslogin_control` shows its status as `deactivated`

I log in using a project-wide SSH key configured in Google Cloud project metadata. The instance uses `cloud-init` to set up SSH keys, etc., but I cannot find any hint as to what might be configured that override PAM's auth mechanism.

**Any hint as to what can possibly override PAM's auth mechanism would be greatly appreciated!**

N.B. The point of this is to eventually enable a PAM module for two-factor authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deny command is ignored for two separate reasons that correspond to two systems which bypass PAM authentication.

1. It is ignored when running `sudo`, because the user is configured with the `NOPASSWD` flag. This flag is enabled in a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` that has the line

   ```
   %google-sudoers ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
   ```

   and my user belongs to the `google-sudoers` group. As the [manual](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html) says:

   > By default, sudo requires that a user authenticate him or herself before running a command. This behavior can be modified via the NOPASSWD tag.

   So using `sudo` bypasses authentication (including PAM) altogether.
2. It is ignored when logging in by SSH using a public key, because SSH public key authentication bypasses PAM. The manual, accessed via `man sshd_config` on Ubuntu 18.04 says

   > If set to yes this will enable PAM authentication using ChallengeResponseAuthentication and PasswordAuthentication in addition to PAM account and session module processing for all authentication types.

   So PAM authentication only works with two types of authentication: challenge response and password. PAM is not used for public key authentication.

   You can force the deny to apply by adding `AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive` to `/etc/sshd_config`. This requires the user to authenticate using two methods: first by public key (this will not use PAM) and then by a challenge response (this will use PAM).